# Does using a fleece cloche hinder plants from getting enough sunlight?

Tags: sunlight, frost, protection

I got some fleece cloth to protect my plants from frost / low temperatures, but it's semi opaque so blocks most sunlight. Is it OK to leave it on through the day (while it's still cold), or do I need to remove it during the day to give the plants enough sunlight?

Answer (score 2):

You should remove it during the day; unfortunately, UK temperatures tomorrow are set to drop but hopefully not to below 5degC during the day where you are; unless you're growing something really tender, it's best to allow daylight to get to the plants. Replace the cloche after 3 or 4 pm for the time being until the weather's warmer, then you can replace it at dusk if temperatures are low enough to be a problem over night.

If it's very cold tomorrow, you may have to wait another day or two for temperatures to rise a bit; the other option is to replace the fleece with thick, clear plastic instead, which will keep warmth in and allow light through, although it will get too hot inside in full sun between 11-3pm, so will need to be removed in that situation.

Comment: It's forecast to be 7 on Tuesday, and then get warmer until returning to nice weather a week later. I've only been planting outside what I've read can handle the cold, keeping the rest in pots until the weather stabilises. So you say I should cover them at 3-4pm; that seems to be the peak temp. though? When would you suggest I cover in the morning? Based on https://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2637627 I'd have guessed around 11am-7pm.

Comment: I've read that plastic can cause humidity problems, which is why I went for the fleece. It still lets some light through (someone on the Amazon page suggested it's ok covering all day, but I trust this site more).

Comment: 3-4pm on non sunny days - after 3 is when the temperature starts to fall on sunless chilly days. If its sunny, fine, do it later. When you say 11am to 7pm, don't you mean 7pm to 11am, overnight in other words? You are correct about the plastic, it does gather moisture on the inside as soon as the sun arrives on it...